# Crystal Reports page break in middle of paragraph

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a database field in crystal reports that contains multiple paragraphs. These paragraphs are based on user input so they are not fixed length. The field may have one, two, or ten paragraphs. My question is, how do I keep from performing a page break in the middle of a paragraph? Move the entire paragraph to the new page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From memory I think you right click on the section and go to section expert then check the box Keep Together.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not concerned about keeping the entire section together just keeping the paragraphs together within the section. No page break in the middle of a paragraph. Thanks for your reply though. :-)